# equivalence in Uniform convergence and space of bounded functions. Requirement of functions $f_n$ and $f$ are bounded function.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

In many typical analysis books, when authors introduce "uniform convergence", they would introduce "space of bounded functions" with supremum norm.

For example, let $X$ be an arbitrary set, $E$ be a complete metric space. Let $B(X,E)$ be the space of bounded functions. Also, let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions and $f$ a function in $B(X,E)$. It is easy to see the following three conditions are equivalent.

It is easy to see the following three conditions are equivalent:

1. $f_n \to f (uni)$
2. $f_n \to f $ in $B(X,E)$
3. $||f_n -f||_{\infty} \to 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

However in Amann's Analysis I.
The authors say that $f_n$ and $f$ needn't be in $B(X,E)$. And they replace the above requirement 2 with 2', as follows:

1. $f_n \to f (uni)$
2. ' $f_n - f \to 0$ in $B(X,E)$ (This means $f_n - f$ is in $B(X,E)$, that is the difference of two functions is in $B(X,E)$)
3. $||f_n -f||_{\infty} \to 0$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is: Is Amann's generalization(The second list of statements) true? To me, it is quite possible that $f_n -f$ is not bounded for some $n$, that is to say: $f_n - f \notin B(X,E)$ for some $n$. I know the basic fact that "In an arbitrary metric space, every convergent sequence is bounded". But when it comes to function spaces, it's not so convinceable to me.

For example, I wonder if there is the possibility that, for every $\epsilon$, there is an integer $N$ s.t. $||f_n - f - 0|| < \epsilon$ for $n > N$. However, there is some $n_0 \leq N$ s.t. $||f_n - f - 0|| = \infty$

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but the second statement is better. Indeed, we *would like* to say that the sequence $(f_n)$ defined by $f_n : x \mapsto x + \dfrac{1}{n}$ converges uniformly to the function $f : x \mapsto x$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Obviously, in that case, neither the $f_n$'s or $f$ is bounded.

Comment: As Kavi's example shows, all that is guaranteed is that eventually $(f_n-f )\in B(X,E)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely possible. Let $X=\mathbb R$, $f_1(x)=x, f_n(x)=0$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $n \geq 2$ for all $x$. Then $\|f_n-f\|=0<\epsilon$ for all $n >1$ wheras $\|f_1-f\|=\infty$.